Psalm 107 seems to suggest a custom of giving public thanks in the Temple for personal rescues; was that a thing in 2nd Temple or modern times?
  107       “Praise the LORD, for He is good; 
     His steadfast love is eternal!” 
  2**Thus let the redeemed of the LORD say, 
     those He redeemed from adversity,** 
     3whom He gathered in from the lands, 
     from east and west, 
     from the north and from the sea. 

  4Some lost their way in the wilderness, 
     in the wasteland; 
     they found no settled place. 
  5Hungry and thirsty, 
     their spirit failed. 
  6In their adversity they cried to the LORD, 
     and He rescued them from their troubles. 
  7He showed them a direct way 
     to reach a settled place. 
  8Let them praise the LORD for His steadfast love, 
     His wondrous deeds for mankind; 
     9for He has satisfied the thirsty, 
     filled the hungry with all good things. 

  10Some lived in deepest darkness, 
     bound in cruel irons, 
     11because they defied the word of God, 
     spurned the counsel of the Most High. 
  12He humbled their hearts through suffering; 
     they stumbled with no one to help. 
  13In their adversity they cried to the LORD, 
     and He rescued them from their troubles. 
  **14He brought them out of deepest darkness, 
     broke their bonds asunder. 
  15Let them praise the LORD for His steadfast love, 
     His wondrous deeds for mankind, 
     16For He shattered gates of bronze, 
     He broke their iron bars.** 

  17There were fools who suffered for their sinful way, 
     and for their iniquities. 
  18All food was loathsome to them; 
     they reached the gates of death. 
  19In their adversity they cried to the LORD 
     and He saved them from their troubles. 
  20He gave an order and healed them; 
     He delivered them from the pits. 
  **21Let them praise the LORD for His steadfast love, 
     His wondrous deeds for mankind. 
  22Let them offer thanksgiving sacrifices, 
     and tell His deeds in joyful song.** 

  23Others go down to the sea in ships, 
     ply their trade in the mighty waters; 
     24they have seen the works of the LORD 
     and His wonders in the deep. 
  25By His word He raised a storm wind 
     that made the waves surge. 
  26Mounting up to the heaven, 
     plunging down to the depths, 
     disgorging in their misery, 
     27they reeled and staggered like a drunken man, 
     all their skill to no avail. 
  28In their adversity they cried to the LORD, 
     and He saved them from their troubles. 
  29He reduced the storm to a whisper; 
     the waves were stilled. 
  30They rejoiced when all was quiet, 
     and He brought them to the port they desired. 
  **31Let them praise the LORD for His steadfast love, 
     His wondrous deeds for mankind. 
  32Let them exalt Him in the congregation of the people, 
     acclaim Him in the assembly of the elders.** 

  33He turns the rivers into a wilderness, 
     springs of water into thirsty land, 
     34fruitful land into a salt marsh, 
     because of the wickedness of its inhabitants. 
  35He turns the wilderness into pools, 
     parched land into springs of water. 
  36There He settles the hungry; 
     they build a place to settle in. 
  37They sow fields and plant vineyards 
     that yield a fruitful harvest. 
  38He blesses them and they increase greatly; 
     and He does not let their cattle decrease, 
     39after they had been few and crushed 
     by oppression, misery, and sorrow. 
  40He pours contempt on great men 
     and makes them lose their way in trackless deserts; 
     41but the needy He secures from suffering, 
     and increases their families like flocks. 

  42The upright see it and rejoice; 
     the mouth of all wrongdoers is stopped. 
  43The wise man will take note of these things; 
     he will consider the steadfast love of the LORD

Jewish Publication Society. (1985). Tanakh: The Holy Scriptures (Ps 107). Jewish Publication Society.

Yes, it's called a Korban Todah. Nowadays we have the HaGomel blessing for public thanksgiving.

How about in the 2nd Temple period?

Presumably the same as the first. Do you have reason to think otherwise?

No, I would expect from Psalm 107 that they did, however, I love to confirm that with some historical reference, lest I be mistaken. And if I'm not mistaken then the historical references would be confirmation.
